# ghc 6.12.1, System.Environment.getArgs and UTF-8

Tags: unicode, haskell, utf-8, ghc

ghc 6.12 dropped separate utf8-string packages since most of its functionality is implemented in stock modules. In particular System.Environment.UTF8 does not exist anymore.

But the following does not work for me if an `arg` is a non-ascii string:

```
import System.Environment
main = do
  [arg] <- getArgs
  putStrLn arg
```

I get some garbage at my terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bug, see

http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/3309

(I assume you mean System.Environment, not System.Environment.UTF8)

The workaround could be to cabal install utf8-sting and use System.Environment.UTF8